# Laravel - how to remove broadcasting stuff, pusher, etc

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pusher

Before I wanted to use pusher for real time chat. Anyways now I dont use it, I upgraded my laravel version from 5.4 to 5.5 now I get strange error about pusher, and I just want to get rid of these. Just I dont know how.

Here is how it looks

https://ibb.co/kvbHAn

I tried to delete some files to check if it will help but no, at last I removed pusher dependency from my composer.json and updated. Still I dont know how to get rid of these. Any ideas?

.env here

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

broadcasting.php

```
'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

 'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'eu',
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: OK I Solved it by removing some codes inside of broadcastingmanager.php . But anyways if you guys have any idea why it happens, you can share.

Answer (score 0):

The `BroadcastingManager.php` creates  the broadcasting drivers that Laravel uses to broadcast events.

You deleted the Pusher library of your dependencies, so the Pusher class wasn't found anymore, that is why it throws that error.

Answer (score 0):

If there is still someone looking for an answer to this:

Solution for me was, to remove all Broadcasting Channels in `routes/channels.php` that I forgot that they use Pusher.